# PyQT QtGui.QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem` that I added to a table by the `createRow` function below:

```
def createRow(self, listA):
    rowNum = self.table.rowCount()
    self.table.insertRow(rowNum)
    i = 0
    for val in listA:
        self.table.setItem(rowNum, i, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(val))
        i += 1
```

Now I have a thread that will update the row values periodically. The function called by the thread is the following:

```
def updateRow(self, listB):
    row = 0
    numRows = self.table.rowCount()
    i = 0
    while i < numRows:

        if listB[0] == self.table.item(i,0):
            row = i
        i+=1
    j = 0
    for val in listB:
        self.table.setItem(row, j, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(val))
        j += 1
```

However, this is not working, because `listB[0]` is a string and `self.table.item(i,0)` is a `QTableWidgetItem`. Anyone know how I could solve this?

In the end, all I want is to update the row for the items that match the first item in the list this function takes as an input (`listB`).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`QTableWidgetItem.text(self)`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidgetitem.html#text) (i.e.: `self.table.item(i,0).text()`) to get the contents of a cell/QTableWidgetItem.